# How to authenticate remote MQ machine, Error when trying to connect

Tags: ibm-mq

```
 Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
 Severity: 10 (Warning)
 Explanation: The queue manager security mechanism has indicated that the userid associated with this request is not authorized to access the object.
```

I am using same version of MQ in both machines and when I try to connect the above error occurs using Windows machines for connection.

Comment: Please update your question with the error seen in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG at the time of the failure. There are very many possibilities that could give the error you show and it would be better if we could help you knowing which one it was.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: It may be silly,I had tried with newer version reinstalling by clearing the total old version files.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1st, make sure you are NOT using a SYSTEM.* channel.  Create a channel for your application.

2nd, add the appropriate permissions (via setmqaut) to allow the UserId to connect to the queue manager and access the queues.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Support Technote "[WMQ 7.1 / 7.5 / 8.0 / 9.0 queue manager RC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED or AMQ4036 or JMSWMQ2013 when using client connection as an MQ Administrator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577137)" has a good write up on diagnosing and resolving this issue.

If you want more specific help, to start with please provide the following details by editing and adding them to your question.  Adding them as comments does not help much since the number of characters are limited and you have no way to format them in a comment.

1. Version of IBM MQ installed on client and queue manager
2. Errors in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG that happen at the same time as the error you receive.
3. SVRCONN channel name that you are connecting too.